# TYPO3 9.x robots.txt route with dynamic sitemap.xml url from the base path?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

My current robots.txt configuration is a staticText route and a hard coded path to the sitemap.xml:

```
routes:
  -
    route: robots.txt
    type: staticText
    content: "User-agent: *\r\nDisallow: /typo3/\r\nDisallow: /typo3_src/\r\nAllow: /typo3/sysext/frontend/Resources/Public/*\r\n\r\nSitemap: https://www.domain.de/sitemap.xml\r\n"
```

Is there a clever and easy way to create a robots.txt with a dynamic generated path to the sitemap.xml via the base path?

The cs_seo extension had this feature included and saved alot of work and type bugs in multidomain setups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use environmental variables inside the site configuration. E.g.

```
Sitemap: %env(BASE_URL_WITH_PROTOCOL)%/sitemap.xml
```

Environmental variable can be set in .htaccess, e.g.:

```
SetEnv BASE_URL_WITH_PROTOCOL http://localhost
```

Documentation - https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/UsingEnvVars.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build a dynamic page in TYPO3 which renders as `robots.txt`?

Make sure you remove all HTML (header and tags) and do a plain TXT rendering. then you can insert anything in the file, including generated URLs.
You may use pure typoscript or fluid templates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That would be a good option. But I think it's a bit too complicated only for the dynamic URL. I would prefer a simpler solution.